# I want this control in .net

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, controls

I want to build a control like the one built into the image below. Its in the file menu for Microsoft Office 2010. I have seen it before but I dont know what it is called.

1. What is it called
2. Where could I find such a control for .net?

[image: The control I want]

Comment: Is it some kind of a ribbon control?

Comment: It's called a "Ribbon" control.

Comment: Isint the ribbon the thing that goes across the top of Office?

Comment: @F Oak - Yes, but this is considered part of it.

Comment: Am I able to use just that part without the rest?

Comment: That's really just a stack of button with fancy graphics.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to create a ribbon that only includes the File menu...

Comment: Do you want the whole "backstage" thing that fills the screen when you click on File, or just the File menu?

Comment: Really just that Info/Recent/New part. I really like that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a full blown Ribbon control, then just take a listbox and style it to look pretty.  Much easier in WPF than WinForms (you didn't specify which you are using)

Comment: less fun, but still doable... you'll have to do a lot a "owner draw" graphics yourself though.  here's a starting point: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sahuja/OwnerDrawListBox11212005014826AM/OwnerDrawListBox.aspx

Comment: I dont know if it is the best solution, but it is the solution I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you're looking for is a Ribbon control.

However, I'm sure you'd be able to create the same effect using an  `ItemsControl` that can handle a `ItemsTemplate` and style that to look the way you need it to look, then have content on the right hand side dynamically change bound to the selected item of the`ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a styled vertical WPF tab control with buttons replacing some of the tab headers. You could probably create something similar in wpf using the style and template features.